# How Do I place headline text behind another headline? (See image)

Tags: html, css

I would like to have headline text, similar to the way it is the image below, behind my headline text.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f66x0txr37klbe0/example.png?dl=0

I thought potentially using a relative position on the first header would allow it but I don't see to be doing that correctly as nothing is appearing.

Can someone please help me with the code to achieve this effect?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code for us to work with?

Comment: Using z-index CSS property, you can achieve this.

Comment: do you try to set both text position absalut?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example using css an no z-index. Using the element creation order you can select which one is on top.

https://jsfiddle.net/s2aqxfr9/

```
<div>
<h1 class="h1-back">
World!
</h1>
<h1 class="h1-front">
Hello!
</h1>
</div>
```

Here is your CSS

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
}
.h1-back {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.h1-front {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this link and let me know if you can see why it isn't appearing at the top of that paragraph? I'm guessing there is probably some padding or margins somewhere that I'm not aware of? The URL is: http://bebossier.advocategroup.cc/ Ideally, that would be the headline text and then the paragraph would appear underneath it.

Comment: That is due the "floating" elements, the ones with `position:absolute`. Most simplistic solution is just to add a desired margin for the div that contains the text (`.e2-9` i believe)...`float:left; margin-top:28%;` would do it..

Other solution, just remove position:absolute of h1-front ...:D

Answer (score -2):

You have to position the second heading (or any other element) absolutely.

Positionthe top left corner in the middle, then fix the position with `transform: translate()`:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%) rotate(-12deg);
```

Don't forget that the element needs a parent with `position: relative` as a reference point.

```css
.hero-section {
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 20vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.another-hero-section {
  position:relative
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}


.special-heading {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 5rem;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}

.special-heading span {
  font-family: 'Caveat Brush', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%) rotate(-12deg);
  color: #127b9b;
  text-shadow: 10px 12px 11px #000000cf;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.special-heading-foreground {
  font-family: 'Caveat Brush', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(12deg);
  color: #749b12;
  text-shadow: 10px 12px 11px #000000cf;
  font-size: 6rem;
  margin: 0;
  line-height 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Caveat+Brush" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="hero-section">
  <h1 class="special-heading">Well, interesting background <span>Foreground</span></h1>
</section>

<section class="hero-section">
  <h1 class="special-heading">Another background</h1>
  <h2 class="special-heading-foreground">Heading&nbsp;2</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add comments to downvotes – so that answers to the question can be improved.

Answer (score -2):

way 1

```
<div class="main">
<img src="img.jpg">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>

.main{
position:relative
}
.main img{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
.main h1{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}
```

way 2:

```
<div class="main">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>

.main{
background-image:url('path/to/img.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```